# Alfresco + Share with LDAP authentication + SSO

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, share, alfresco

I am trying to enable the SSO option for the Alfresco and Share webapp. The authentication is made via LDAP and it all works fine for Alfresco and CIFS but when I try to access some components that are located in the Share webapp I am asked for the username and password.

So is there a way to get automatically logged in to the share app if I am logged in the alfresco app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've enabled SSO for share.

You have to enable the external subsystems to achieve this.
Take a look at the [wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Authentication_Subsystems#External)